# Mobile menu drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the responsive menu script from PureCss example. I'd like for the menu to disappear after the user clicks a link.  How could I automatically hide the menu after a click has been made?
I've tried to use `hide()` or `.fadeOut()`, but it doesn't work

```
https://jsfiddle.net/bpvm8b5L/3/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Event Listener to your anchor elements inside the menu that on click trigger a function that reproduce the action of when the hamburger menu icon is pressed, so it removes the class active from

- `<div id="layout" class=" active">`
- `<a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link active">…</a>`
- `<div id="menu" class='active'>…</div>`

So try to add in your ui.js file, inside your main function:

```
var ulElem = document.getElementById('ulElem');

ulElem.onclick = function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target.classList.value);
     if(e.target.classList.value === "pure-menu-link") {
     toggleClass(layout, active);
     toggleClass(menu, active);
     toggleClass(menuLink, active);
     }
}
```

And remember to set the id name of the ui element on your HTML file as `id=uiElem`.

Comment: It returns an error Uncaught ReferenceError: active is not defined

Comment: Okay, i forgot about additional var active = 'active'; and it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can as well try this

In html, assuming you have something like this:

```
<nav id="toggleMenu">
   //all your links
</nav>
```

In jquery,

```
 $('#toggleMenu li      a').click(function(){
    $('#toggleMenu).hide(200);
});
```